# (Symfony 4) What replaced Symfony's earlier app/config/config.yml file?

Tags: symfony, config

I'm using Symfony 4 and I want to use a bundle that is not supported by Symfony 4, so the configuration documentation is old (Symfony 2.0).

If the Symfony 2.0 documentation tells you to put something in `app/config/config.yml`, what is the equivalent of this `app/config/config.yml` file in Symfony 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent would be `config/packages/LIB_NAME.yaml`

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/configuration.html#using-the-bundle-extension) you can see:

```
# config/packages/acme_social.yaml
acme_social:
    twitter:
        client_id: 123
        client_secret: your_secret
```

Comment: Hi Mark, so I can just create my own yam file?

Comment: @BrentHeigold yes you can! With Sf4 if you are using flex, some libs have their recipes which creates that file but if they don't have it, you just create it. Everything from `config/packages/*` is autoloaded